# Format string vulnerabiltiy, overwrite variable

Tags: c, string, security, printf, format-string

I already googled and read through different papers, but couldn't find a solution.

I programmed a little c program, in which I want to overwrite the argument of the function.

```
void test(int test) {
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x\n");
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %n\n");
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x\n");
    if (test == 1) {
        printf("BOO\n");
    } else {
        printf("YEE\n");
    }

}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program, if I run it with this setup is the following:

```
fff6c602 f7d61138 5658b559 0 0 fff6b698 5658b5f4 1
Segmentation fault
```

The 1 is the argument of the function, which I want to overwrite. But as you can see if I use %n to overwrite it, the program crashes, though I set up the printf pointer right.

Does anybody know, why this is happening?

Comment: **Undefined behavior**. For any further explanations, you'd have to look at the concrete implementation, including compiler and C library, processor architecture and possibly operating system.

Comment: notice that the `%n` needs to have an argument that is *pointer to int*. `1` is not a proper value of type `int *`, it is `int`. The simplest fix would be to pass in `int *test`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks for that information! I changed the function like you suggested, but it didn't change anything of the result :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question *adding* the new code

Answer (score 1):

from `man - printf(3)`

> **%n**
>   The number of characters written so far is stored into the integer
>   indicated by the ***int  (or variant) pointer argument**. No argument is
>   converted.

Now you're trying to do is write something to address `0x1`, which leads to SIGSEGV for sure.
If you want to overwrite the argument of the function, you need to find the pointer to the argument for `%n`.